# DMS Task fail for EC2 oracle as source

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

Last failure message
Last Error Endpoint initialization failed. Task error notification received from subtask 0, thread 0 [reptask/replicationtask.c:2859] [1020401] Cannot retrieve Oracle archived Redo log destination ids; Failed to set stream position on context 'now'; Error executing command; Stream component failed at subtask 0, component

Answer (score 0):

Is your backup on? If your backup retention is set to 0, then your backup is off, thus disabling your archive logs. Please check whether the archive log is enabled at target or not

Comment: Im using Ec2 as source not RDS

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error on a EC2 instance, the archived mode is on and the retention policy is:

using target database control file instead of recovery catalog
RMAN configuration parameters for database with db_unique_name MYDB are:

```
CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO REDUNDANCY 1; # default
CONFIGURE BACKUP OPTIMIZATION OFF; # default
CONFIGURE DEFAULT DEVICE TYPE TO DISK; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP ON; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '%F'; # default
CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE DISK PARALLELISM 1 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET; # default
CONFIGURE DATAFILE BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE MAXSETSIZE TO UNLIMITED; # default
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION FOR DATABASE OFF; # default
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION ALGORITHM 'AES128'; # default
CONFIGURE COMPRESSION ALGORITHM 'BASIC' AS OF RELEASE 'DEFAULT' OPTIMIZE FOR LOAD TRUE ; # default
CONFIGURE RMAN OUTPUT TO KEEP FOR 7 DAYS; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY TO NONE; # default
CONFIGURE SNAPSHOT CONTROLFILE NAME TO '/oracle/db/1900/dbs/snapcf_MYDB.f'; # default
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29876715)